# what's the use of lambda in this case

Tags: python, django, lambda

I used lambda several times. When reading this tutorial [django-autoslug](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug)

there are two examples:

```
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
```

and more complex:

```
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=lambda instance: instance.title,
                         unique_with=['author__name', 'pub_date__month'],
                         slugify=lambda value: value.replace(' ','-'))
```

I'm interested in that row: `populate_from='title'` and `populate_from=lambda instance: instance.title`
**What's the difference?**
And can you give some tutorial(not documentation) with examples of `lambda`?

Comment: Python's own tutorial: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions. *"I used lambda several times"* - and you don't know what it does?

Comment: From the docs `populate_from – string or callable: if string is given, it is considered as the name of attribute from which to fill the slug. If callable is given, it should accept instance parameter and return a value to fill the slug with.` http://pythonhosted.org/django-autoslug/fields.html

Comment: , which should mean that there's no difference between `'title'` and `lambda instance: instance.title` here.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `lambda` is just a quick one-line way to make a function. It would be equivalent to:

```
def slugFunction(someInstance):
    return someInstance.title

slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=slugFunction)
```

You could also make a slug that that doesn't have anything to do with the model field. For instance, you could use an epoch:

```
import time

slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=lambda i: return str(time.time()))
```

(Note that AutoSlugField will always pass the model instance to the function, so your function must take one argument, even if it doesn't use it.)

99% of the time, you'll probably base the slug on a model field, so there's a shortcut for that. AutoSlugField could never have enough built-in functions to handle the other use cases, so it lets you specify a function yourself.

Their documentation is confusing because they illustrate the same use case two different ways. - As L3viathan points out in the comments above, there is no difference between `'title'` and `lambda instance: instance.title`.